# call back of completion of iteration is not getting called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

using https://github.com/caolan/async
struggling for getting run the loop by async so finding end of execution of loop is handled .
and

```
 results=[]
async.forEach(nfiles, function(item ){
    console.log(item);
        results.push(item);


}, function(err){ /// result call back 
    console.log('in last');

});
```

why console  is not coming in result call back  ?

suppose nfiles is an array and on each iteration put the item in results so at the end of iteration it should console  the inlast in console but not doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of your [forEach](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach) -- the iterator function -- needs to take in a callback as an argument and call it when it executes (to indicate it is done). You need to call the callback like this:

```
results=[]
async.forEach(nfiles, function(item, callback){
    console.log(item);
    results.push(item);
    callback(null, item);

}, function(err){ /// result call back 
    console.log('in last');

});
```

(untested)